# Java stream map result of reduce

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

Let's say I have a collection of string

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

and I want to get a collection of string combinations via stream api

```
["a", "ab", "abc"]
```

My solution is to use `reduce` in this way:

```
final List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
List.of("a", "b", "c").stream().reduce("", (s, s2) -> {
                    items.add(s + s2);
                    return s + s2;
                });
```

In this case I got what I need in items collection: `["a", "ab", "abc"]`.
Is there a more pretty way to get this one with standard stream api?

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow.  It may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but please remember to check [their rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting.

Comment: I think that using for loop would be cleaner in this case

Comment: Yup: `String combined = ""; for (String str : collection) items.add(combined += str);`

Comment: reduce should not have any side effects

Comment: @Lino agreed. A side effect free solution also could take advantage of parallel processing. It would look much less "pretty", though (my attempt ended up at around 10 lines).